# AngularJS ng-options/Typeahead expression syntax

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I was trying to find the AngularJS select with ng-options or Typeahead expression syntax but I couldn't find the whole thing in one place, so I gather information from here and there and this is what I came up with:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expression syntax (This is the full syntax, most of it are optional):

```
(ObjectForModel) as (stringRepresentation for the UI) for (OneObjectFromList) in (ListOfObjects) | (Filter1) | (Filter2) ...
```

Example: Lets say we have a list of Students:

```
var StudentList = [{firstName: "Jhon",lastName:"Smith" id:1},{firstName: "Clint",lastName:"Eastwood" id:2} ];
```

Lets say that we wanna use this list in a typeAhead input but:
1. We want our popup drop down to display: "first name - last name" but when a user select an item we want the whole item from the list to be populate in the ng-model.
2. We want to filter the select to show only 5 elements
3. We want the pop up drop down list to display only what is relevant base on the user input.

So this is how it looks like:

```
uib-typeahead="student as (student.firstName +' - ' + student.lastName) for student in studentList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:5"
```

If you guys have something more to add please do, I know I could have use it...

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the template ( for example displaying a field in a particular way, and on click set the input with another one )

in the html file :

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="deterFormACTemplate.html">
        <a ng-bind-html="match.model.displayed | unsafe"></a>
    </script>


     <input typeahead-template-url="deterFormACTemplate.html" 
               uib-typeahead="item as item.field for item in autocomplete(...)"
               typeahead-on-select="mymodel=$model.field;"
               typeahead-wait-ms="500" />
```

in the controller

```
     $scope.autocomplete = function ( ){
            return  [ {'field':'..', "displayed":"..."},{'field':'..', "displayed":"..."}, .. ];
     }
```